# Как запретить phpstorm видеть файл или папку в рабочем каталоге проекта?

Tags: phpstorm

Есть пару файлов и каталог которые нужны ИМЕННО в рабочем каталоге проекта, но которые нужно запретить видеть PHPStorm-у.

Есть какая-нить похожая штука типа .gitignore в git или настройка, но только для PHPStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть - Mark directory as/Excluded. Исключенные папки не индексируются, они как бы находятся вне проекта (хотя по умолчанию видны в Project tool window). Файлы таким образом исключить нельзя. Но можно их прописать в `Settings/Editor/File types, Ignore files and folders`

Comment: Спасибо @lena !